# Interpreting the amplitude damping channel

Tags: quantum-information

In page 380 of Nielsen and Chuang (Quantum information), there's a statement about the amplitude damping channel, which is defined by the operators $E_0 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & \sqrt{1-\lambda}\end{bmatrix}$ and $E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \sqrt{\lambda}\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ where $\lambda$ can be interpreted as the probability of losing a quantum of energy.

> The $E_1$ operation changes a |1⟩ state into a |0⟩ state, corresponding to the physical process of losing a quantum of energy to the environment. $E_0$ leaves |0⟩ unchanged, but reduces the amplitude of a |1⟩ state; physically, this happens because a quantum of energy was not lost to the environment, and thus the environment now perceives it to be more likely that the system is in the |0⟩ state, rather than the |1⟩ state

what does it mean that a quantum of energy was not lost to the environment?  The amplitude of |1> state is reduced by $E_0$, so some energy is lost, if it is not in the environment, where could it go?

Comment: Hi, you should define $E_0$ and $E_1$ so that we can better understand what N&C are talking about without going looking for the book!